# installing gnucobol on windows10

Tags: cobol

I have a problem with installing gnucobol 2.2.
I get an error message telling me there's no c compiler found. I run windows10 on my laptop

```
$ ./configure  
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c  
checking whether build environment is sane... yes  
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p  
checking for gawk... gawk  
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... no  
checking whether make supports nested variables... no  
checking whether CFLAGS can be modified... yes  
checking for gcc... no  
checking for xlc... no  
checking for cc... no  
configure: error: in `/cygdrive/c/gnucobol-2.2-rc':  
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH  
See `config.log' for more details
```

can someone please help me with this problem?
thank you :)

Comment: Based on the error you received, what have you tried so far to resolve the problem?

Comment: i tried 'sudo apt-get build-essential'. cause thats the only thing i found on the internet atm

Comment: it says sudo command not found(im using cygwin64 terminal for this)

Comment: @A.Creupelandt, Stackoverflow really isn't the place to discuss software installations.  Visit the main SourceForge discussion group at https://sourceforge.net/p/open-cobol/discussion/help/ and ask there. Cygwin uses setup.exe (or setup-x86.exe or setup-x86_64.exe) instead of apt-get.  And there is no sudo in Cygwin, you run setup as an Administrator for super user permissions. You will need to install quite a few packages from the Devel Cygwin setup group to get GnuCOBOL up and running.  Visit SourceForge for more help.

Comment: @Brian Tiffin thank you for the link it helped me alot :)

Comment: Running COBOL on Windows? Have you also tried attaching horses to the front of your car? :-)

Answer (score 2):

Whilst not directly related to the "./configure" question, a general "easy" answer to "installing gnucobol on windows10" might be:

1. Use a package manager such as chocolatey

https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/gnucobol

This doesn't work at the moment due to an issue with the packaging, but generally speaking is likely the easiest "just install" option on native Windows

2. Install WSL and then "apt install gnucobol" in there.

WSL is "Windows Subsystem for Linux".  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install .  The drawback of this approach is that if you're using gnucobol to create objects, libraries or executables (as opposed to just C code) then you'll get Linux objects, libraries or executables, which likely isn't what you want on Windows.  However, for just getting access to the environment, it's likely the fastest way there.

Comment: Note: choco should work again and you may also use the binaries it installs directly - found at https://arnoldtrembley.com/GnuCOBOL.htm

Answer (score 0):

Cygwin has its own package manager: setup-x86_64.exe.

This is a GUI application where you'd enable [the contents of the base-essentials meta package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/build-essential), at least "gcc" and "make".
To build GnuCOBOL from source you'll need to add additional packages, see [GnuCOBOL's DEPENDENCIES file](https://sourceforge.net/p/gnucobol/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/DEPENDENCIES.md).

IF you'd want to install without the GUI, then as an alternative to `apt-get` you *could* [use `cyg-get`](https://cygwin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/). Instead of "sudo", which doesn't exist you may need to start Cygwin as Administrator, if you didn't do a user-install.

Apart from this question: as this question shows that you aren't using Cygwin for development in general and likely just want to use it on GnuCOBOL: have a look at the [official MinGW packages](https://arnoldtrembley.com/GnuCOBOL.htm), this is just a download, extract and double click to "set_env.cmd", then you're ready to go.